# MathJax, create a fraction, but don't center it relative to text

Tags: mathjax, tex

I want to be able to make a fraction. Which I have done:

[image]

However, I want the numerator to be regular text. I just want to underline "whose company" and place a **B** *below* it. So something more like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 \mathop{\underline{\text{Whose Company}}}\limits_{\hbox{B}}
```